# Add Items into Empty array in Reducer give Error 'TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.'

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, redux, reducers

I'm tried to declare any empty array in reducer and trying to add some objects in it dynamically.But I got this error when i try to add new item in it.'TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.'It means that you don't have any array in which you are trying to add new item?.How's it possible.Here is my reducer state.

```
const initialState = {
  
  recentSearches: [],
 
};
```

here is my function firing up

```
const handleItem = async (item) => {
    let recent = [...recentSearches];
    recent.push(item);
    new Promise((rsl, rej) => {
      addSearchItem(recent, rsl, rej);
    })
      .then((res) => {
        navigation.navigate('SearchDetail', {text: item.name});

        // console.log('Zaid ----->', res);
      })
      .catch((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  };
```

here is the action to reducer

```
export const addSearchItem = (data, rsl, rej) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_SEARCH,
        recentSearches: data,
      });
      rsl();
    } catch (err) {
      rej();
    }
  };
};
```

here is the case

```
case ADD_SEARCH:
      return {
        ...state,
        recentSearches: action.recentSearches,
      };
```

Comment: Can you provide your reducer code where you handle ADD_SEARCH action?

Comment: provide your case handle in reducer ?

Comment: I've added @MuhammadAshfa

Comment: your previous data of recentSearches is iterable, so you cannot change it to new pointer type of data, you can try this `recentSearches: [...action.recentSearches]`

Comment: Try using this way like let recent = [...this.state.recentSearches];

Answer (score 0):

you can update an array in redux immutably in this way

```
return {
...state,
recentSearches:state.recentSearches.concat(item),
}
```

I hope this will help for more follow this
https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns

Comment: error      TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of null

Comment: make sure you are modifying the above code for your array name and your item is not null

Comment: i did,in reducer contact is null

Comment: please share your code snippet, so that I can see what causes the error

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you trying to copy an undefined array in your reducer. eg:

```
const newList = [...state.someList];
```

In this case, 'someList' is undefined or not an array. make sure your spelling or you are using the correct array.

Answer (score 0):

Not Fixed yet the solutions provided above